# Laptop getting hot after installing ubuntu 12.04:possibly a videocard driver problem

Tags: drivers, graphics

Today i installed ubuntu 12.04.2 version.  And my laptop runs really hot.My video card is  ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4650.This is not my first ubuntu installation.i have used ubuntu in past and "additional driver"program recognized my graphic card and installed necessary drivers.Now my graphic card is not recognized in additional drivers.
Please tell me how to install necessary drivers for my graphic card.Last time i installed ubuntu ,i had to face to this heat problem because of graphic card drivers.

Answer (score 0):

The newer Catalyst drivers do not support the HD4xxx series anymore, so you have to download the old drivers manually and install them.

Download your driver [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx)

And then do what [this](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide) website tells you.

Comment: it didnt work.It says your graphic card is not supported by this driver.

Comment: Did you selecet:
_Notebook Drivers_ >
_Radeon HD Series_ >
_Mobility Radeon HD 4xxx Series_ >
And then Linux, x86_64 or x86 depending on wether you have a 64bit installation or a 32bit installation?

Comment: yeah`i selected them correct